# Is there an automatic way to stop scrapy crawler when it results some errors?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

In general, I run my **scrapy** cralwer using the following command:

```
scrapy crawl <sipder_name>
```

after running, it crawls the desired elements from target resource, but I have to monitor the results showed on the screen to find errors(if any) and stop the crawler manually.

How can I **automate** this procedure? Is there an automatic way to stop the crawler when it can't  crawl a desired element and failed on fetching that?

Answer (score 3):

spider.py:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider


class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'somespider'

    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://example.com']


    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            something()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise CloseSpider("Some error")   
        # if you want to catch a bad status you can also do:
        # if response.status != 200: .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for logging. There is the documentation for logging [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html?highlight=logger).

I find useful to use:

```
import logging
import scrapy

logger = logging.getLogger('mycustomlogger')

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['https://scrapy.org']

    def parse(self, response):
        logger.info('Parse function called on %s', response.url)
```

Comment: You can then automate your logs response into your database, like ELK stack.